# Как создать массив из ArrayList?

Tags: java

Есть `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Double> ald = new ArrayList();
```

Нужно создать массив такого типа:

```
Double[] arr_ald = new Double[10];
```

Но вместо `Double` должен быть тип как у `ald` (`ArrayList<Double>`), чтобы можно было сделать перебор массива:

```
arr_ald[i]
```

и брать элементы:

```
ald.get(j)
```

Comment: Да, я некорректно написал. Речь про массив из списков состоящих из Double.

Comment: Можно сделать так: `ArrayList[] array = new ArrayList[10];`. Создать `ArrayList<Double>[] array = new ArrayList<Double>[10];` не получится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создать массив из объектов параметризованного типа (коими являются `ArrayList<Double>`) нельзя. Об этом говорится [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays).

Так что тут либо использовать raw type `ArrayList` (со всеми появляющимися при этом проблемами):

```
ArrayList<Double> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0));
ArrayList<Double> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(3.0, 4.0));
ArrayList[] lists = { list1, list2 };
for (ArrayList list : lists)
{
    for (Object o : list)
    {
        double value = (double)o;
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Либо создавать обёртку для `ArrayList<Double>`:

```
public class ArrayListDouble extends ArrayList<Double> { }
```

и использовать её:

```
ArrayListDouble list1 = new ArrayListDouble();
list1.addAll(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0));
ArrayListDouble list2 = new ArrayListDouble();
list2.addAll(Arrays.asList(3.0, 4.0));
ArrayListDouble[] lists = { list1, list2 };
for (ArrayListDouble list : lists)
{
    for (double value : list)
    {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не знаю, правильно ли  я сделал, но я создал класс в котором объявил ArrayList<Double> cat = new ArrayList(); и отдельно создал массив из таких классов. Вроде получилось удобно.

Comment: @kaaa корректнее будет `ArrayList<Double> cat = new ArrayList<>();`. Может, это комментарий "съел" `<>`, но терять эту часть в коде не стоит. Я так понял, вы создали класс, в котором список хранится в качестве поля. Если этот класс имеет право на существование не просто как обёртка (то есть имеет ещё какой-то функционал и/или является абстракцией относительно способа хранения данных), то это нормально. Если же просто как обёртка, то вместо создания в нём кучи методов (`add`, `get` и т.д.) можно просто сделать `extends ArrayList<Double>` без хранения чего-либо внутри класса (как в ответе).

Comment: Да, этот класс я буду использовать не только как обертку. ("Не было бы счастья, да несчастье помогло"). Я его приспособил и для других задач. За скобочки "<>" спасибо, а то я их уже пропустил.

Answer (score 1):

Массив списков (как и любых других параметризированных типов) создать нельзя.

[Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays):

> You cannot create arrays of parameterized types. For example, the following code does not compile:
>
> ```
> List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];  // compile-time error
> ```